# Is it possible to highlight a whole inbox entry, based on its category?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

There is the possibility to assign a category to a mail, and as a result the mail gets a coloured rectangle:

[image: Screenshot]

Is it possible to colour the whole message, like this?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, changing the background color is not possible in Outlook natively.  The closest you can get is changing the font properties, such as the family, color or formatting (bold, italics, etc.)  And as far as colors go, you are limited to a basic 16 colors.

If you decide that this could work for you, this is how you would go about doing it:

#### Views: Conditional Formatting

1. Click on the **View** tab on the Ribbon, then **View Settings**.
   [image: View -> View Settings]
2. Click on **Conditional Formatting**.
   [image: Conditional Formatting]
3. Click the **Add** button to add a new rule.
   [image: Add a new rule]
4. Name the rule and then click the **Condition** button.
   [image: Name the new rule and then go into the Condition settings]
5. Click the **More Choices** tab, then the **Categories** button, then choose the category you want.
   [image: More Choices -> Categories -> Choose Category]
6. Click **OK** and then click the **Font** button to customize the font.
   [image: Enter the Font settings]
7. Customize the font settings to your liking.  Click **OK** when done.
   [image: Customize the font settings]
8. Click **OK** to get out of the Conditional Formatting dialog and again to get out of the View Customization dialog.
   You will now see your rule in action.
   [image: Conditional formatting rule in action]

I typically use these rules to change the font color of mail entries where I am in the "To:" field or the "Cc:" field, or mails from me that I receive (such as sending to a distribution list of which I am a member).  There's a lot of support for different conditions, but unfortunately, you can only alter the font and not the background.

I hope this helps.